# debug and break on null pointer exceptions only

Tags: c#, nullpointerexception

[image]

I have to debug a big messy C# tool which I didn't write, that parses an Excel file in a specific format (containing exotic data in quantity).

The run of the tool lasts for about 15 minutes and produces an error report (thousands of entries in general). Trouble is that the coder has used exceptions everywhere for his "error reporting", and I need to find a few null pointer exceptions that occur about 2% of the time. I'm not even talking about all the catching, grouping, rethrowing which is bad practice in my understanding, both in terms of consistency and rapidity of execution.

Is there a way to only break on Null Pointer Exceptions in Visual Studio (2008) or at least a trick to filter most exceptions ? Breaking on all exceptions is not an option here.

Comment: yes but the fact that lots of exceptions of caught, rethrown, taken out of context makes it hard.

Comment: have you tried to use application.unhandled exceptions and catch type of exception over there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Visual Studio, under Debug -> Exceptions, you can specify for which exception it should break.

You can find the NullReferenceException under:

**CommonLanguage Runtime Exceptions**

- System

  - System.NullReferenceException

Comment: Totally forgot about the fact that you could CHOOSE the exception to stop on. =D

Comment: Use the Find feature... it will take a lot less time then rooting through the tree structure.  It's under "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" - "System"

Comment: Does simply what I needed, and bingo! The error came from a framework I'm using, so that saved a headache.

Answer (score 4):

the fastest thing I think of is to find all `catch (`strings and replace them with

```
catch (NullReferenceException npe)
        {
        //something your logging here
        }
        catch (
```

then add breakpoints if you need only in these catch sections

Comment: In my experience, this is much faster than Debug -> Exceptions that Rik suggested. Rik's makes the program run much slower.

Comment: Yes but I have the feeling the troubles come from some Catch blocks, but there's a zillion of them.

Comment: @mihail: If the errors are already being caught and logged somehow, then there could be many places that this is required.

Comment: that's why I suggested to replace "catch (" string - the errors are logged in some catch sections, probably "catch (Exception e)". If you add the block and add breakpoints in there, the debugger will stop only on NRE, not every exception

Answer (score 4):

Within Visual Studio press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> or goto <kbd>Debug</kbd>-><kbd>Exceptions</kbd>. In the dialog that appears check the 'Thrown' box for NullReferenceException. You may wish to use the Find button to locate it.

[image]

Comment: It's under Debug, not Build.

Answer (score 1):

Put a tick in the "Thrown" column here:

```
Debug -> Exceptions -> Common Language Runtime Exceptions -> System -> System.NullReferenceException
```